# 晴れて usage and meaning

Tags: grammar, words

要はその期限まで、誰にも私たちの事をしゃべらず、また、勝手に**死ななければ晴れて**自由の身ってこと。

I don't understand what that bold part mean.

Is this a set phrase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

晴れて is a adverb and it means "overtly","publicly","openly". So 晴れて自由の身だ means I am openly free. See [晴れて in goo 辞書](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/180580/meaning/m0u/%E6%99%B4%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6/).

For example, 晴れて夫婦になる, 晴れて無罪となる.